# find the width of option which has maximum text

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one selectbox inside the div

```
<div>
    <select>
    <option value="0">apple</option>
    <option value="1">orange</option>
    <option value="2">bannan fruit</option>
    </select>
<div>
```

i want to find the width of `option` which has maximum text and want to set it on `div`

```
var max_length = -1;
$('option').each(function(){
  max_length = Math.max(max_length, $(this).text().length);
});
alert(max_length);
```

i tried in this way but its giving the number of alphabet not the width of option

any help will be very gr8 thanx

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).width()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectWidth = $("select").width()
```

Will give you the max Width of the html select

Assign width to div

```
$(".divClass").width(selectWidth);
```

Comment: Yes it will give you width of option itself, change your option text length and see..

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle link to prove](http://jsfiddle.net/yW9wD/)

```
 var m = '0';  
var n = '';
$('option').each(
 function(){
     if($(this).html().length > m){
     m = $(this).html().length;
     n = $(this).html();
     }
 });
$('#text').html(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <select id="sel">
    <option value="0">apple</option>
    <option value="1">orange</option>
    <option value="2">bannan fruit</option>
    </select>
<div>

$(document).ready(function(){

    alert(($('#sel option:selected').text()).length);
});
```